# Easiest way to move everything, including custom structs, from an IDA Pro IDB to another?

Tags: ida

I have analyzed a 32 bit version of an executable, defined many structs, renamed many things and so on.

Now i want to move everything, including the structs that i defined, to the IDB of the 64 bit version of the same application. Because i know that at least many of the structs and functions are the same so at least i need to move these structs there.

How to do this in IDA pro? (using 7.6)